# File search by inputed values

Tags: php, file, search

I have problem with file search. I have 2 text forms in which I want to input value for search in file. But somehow if I write input in one of the form, it is also displayed in other line (I don't want this). Also my search works only by one of searching options (where variable is $search).

```
<?php

function f_display(){

global $file;



?>

<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>>
    <input type=text name=search value="<?php echo $_GET['search'] ; ?>">
    <input type=submit value=Message_Search>
    </form>
<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>>
    <input type=text name=search value="<?php echo $_GET['search'] ; ?>">
    <input type=submit value=Name_Search>
    </form>

    <?php

    $f    = fopen($file,"r");
    $x     = 'bgcolor="#AAAAAA"';
    $y     = 'bgcolor="#FFFFFF"';
    $search =  $_GET['search'];
    $searchname = $_GET['search'];


    echo "<table width=50% border=1><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>vardas</th><th>nikas</th><th>pranesimas</th></tr>";

    if (filesize($file)>0){

        while (!feof ($f)) {
            $string = fgets ($f,1000);
            $part = explode ( "|" , $string );


            if ( @stristr($part[2] , $search) == false and $search) continue ;

            echo "<tr $tr_spec ><td><a href = \"index.php?aaa=2&id=$i\"></a></td><td>" . $part[0] . "</td><td>". $part[1]." </td><td>". $part[2] ."</td></tr>";



            if ( @stristr($part[0] , $searchname) == false and $searchname) continue ;

            echo "<tr $tr_spec ><td><a href = \"index.php?aaa=2&id=$i\"></a></td><td>" . $part[0] . "</td><td>". $part[1]." </td><td>". $part[2] ."</td></tr>";

       } // while
    } // if

    fclose ($f);
    echo "</table>";


?>
```

File looks like:

```
John|J0N|Hello
Peter|P3tE|Wow
Paul|PO|Nice
```

Maybe you could offer me something or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're not closing the function you've created: `function f_display(){`
2. You're using deprecated HTML, `<input type=submit value=Message_Search>` you don't put quotes to give a value, you're giving a direct value. The good way is: `<input type="submit" value="Message Search">`
3. You're using insecure methods like `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` while writing
4. You're calling undefined vars `$_GET['search']` (because on first load they are not defined yet) and it can produce an error. (TIP: Use filter_input())
5. You're using the `width=50%` which is not longer used in HTML5
6. You're using the explode method and I'm not sure why you don't use the strpos (that located where is a word, and that's what you're trying)
7. If you want to exlode line by line to the last one, the fgets require it second argument to this number: 4096 (extracted from https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php , I have never used that method before)
8. Where are you defining the $tr_spec var?

And now I'll give you my PHP script correction, if you want to use it feel free on doing it:

```
  // Check if the form has been sent or if the page was accessed using the GET method.
  if( filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_METHOD" ) !== "GET" ) {
    die();
  }

  $search = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "search" );

  //  Check if the searh input has been correctly fill
  if( !isset( $search ) ) {
    die();
  }

  // Let's return here to prevent open an empty file
  if( filesize( $file ) <= 0 ) {
    return;
  }

  $openedFile = fopen( $file, "r" );

  // I was using the here document option, echo <<<END END; but it didn't work due to my text editor...
  echo "
  <table style=\"width: 50%; border-width: 1px;\">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>vardas</th>
        <th>nikas</th>
        <th>pranesimas</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  ";

  // Let's save in buffer the current line and then navigate through all of them

  while( ( $buffer = fgets( $openedFile, 4096 ) ) !== false ) {

    // Here we check if the line has the searched word
    if( strpos( $buffer, $search ) !== false ) {

      $part = explode( "|", $buffer );

      echo "
          <tr>
            <td>" . $part[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . $part[1] . "</td>
            <td>" . $part[2] . "</td>
            <td>" . $part[3] . "</td>
          </tr>
      ";

    }//.if

  }//.while

  echo "
    </tbody>
  </table>
  ";
```

With the comments I explain everything, but I've just corrected the end script problems, you have yet some problems to solve. I hope this helped!

Comment: What if I want to search in 2 parts separately. How I could make it. Your script is searching in whole file, I need to search by 2parts

Comment: What do you mean with 2 different parts? If you mean 2 different files just add a while before the first one, if you want just a part change the explode or use strpos to exclude parts, also you can use the substr method

Comment: I mean file has 3columns, each column is part. I need to make search in 1 and 3 column. I can make easy search for one column, but I can't make it on two columns (part[0] and part[2]).

Comment: No! strpos() method will look for each word within a column. If you just want to test if a column is ok first explode the code and then do the strpos on each part

Comment: Maybe you can offer me, how to work with forms? How to make 2 different inputs one for part[1] and other for part[2]. And later make search, which depends on which value is inserted.

Comment: I can not give you direct code, but the w3schools have a great tutorial of how them work: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Thank you, your example and comments helped me a lot :)